# Evaluate $ 1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{4^3}+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Evaluate $$ 1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{4^3}+\dots$$

All i could do was to see that $$\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2.1+1},\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{2.2+1},\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{2.3+1},\dots$$

SO, we should be able to write

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{4^3}+\dots=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}.\frac{1}{4^n}$$

This is what i could simplify the given question to...

But, this is doing me no good.. I could not go any further..

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear this.

I would request users who are trying to help me to just give necessary hints but not post it as answer.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you evaluate the power series $\sum x^{2n+1}/(2n+1)$? Maybe by differentiating?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what does it mean to evaluate :O I can differentiate this and get $\sum x^{2n}$

Comment: OK, can you sum that series? and then antidifferentiate to get a formula for the power series I asked about?

Comment: yes.. I can sum that series resulting $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.. and then, I should take integral of this right?? it would then be.. $\ln(1-x^2).\frac{1}{-2x}$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That is not correct; try differentiating your answer and you will see that it is not what you started with.

Comment: @User-33433 : Oh my bad.. Yes.. now i could see that i am wrong and the integration will be $\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x))$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), for $|x|<1,$

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$$

$$\text{and }\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$$

Now subtract

Observe that  $$ 1 + \frac13\frac14+\frac15\frac1{4^2}+\frac17\frac1{4^3}+\cdots$$

$$=2\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac1{2r+1}\left(\frac12\right)^{2r+1}$$

Comment: I could see that $$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$$

$$=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots -(-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots)$$

$$=2x+ 2\frac{x^3}{3}+2 \frac{x^5}{5}+\dots...$$

$$=2(x+ \frac{x^3}{3}+ \frac{x^5}{5}+\dots...)$$ but i am not sure how to go further,,,

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, as $\frac12<1,$ put $x=\frac12$ and may use $\log a-\log b=\log (a/b)$

Comment: yes yes,,, $$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2(x+ \frac{x^3}{3}+ \frac{x^5}{5}+\dots...) $$ and for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we would have

$$\ln(\frac{3}{2})-\ln(\frac{1}{2})=2(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^3}{3}+ \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^5}{5}+\dots...)=\ln(3)$$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, one resembling series : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition. It is also useful to know $e^+e^{-x}$

Comment: I am familiar with expansion for $e^x$.. I was actually trying to manipulate given sum  so as to make that look as exponential of something but i could not do that,,,

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, yes $!$ symbol makes a lot of difference.:)

Comment: Yes Yes... I agree :) :)