# Need someone to confirm whether I've done this series problem correctly.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{2^n}{3^n}$

I need to determine whether it is divergent or convergent. If it is convergent, I need to find the sum.

The first thing I noticed is that it looks like an alternating series. I also noticed that with some slight manipulation that I can make $b_n$ appear as a geometric series.

$b_n = (\frac{2}{3})^n $

Before I get ahead of myself, should I be looking at this like an alternating series? By that I mean, I need to check the following:

- Check to see if the limit of $b_n$ = 0.
- Check to see that the $b_n$ is decreasing.

Or should I be looking at this like a geometric series in which r < 1, therefore it converges to $\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}$

My thoughts are that I should be doing the former.

If that is correct, it does look like the function is decreasing. However, the limit looks like it is going to infinity rather than 0. So then I still don't know whether it is convergent or divergent.

I feel like I have done it wrong. What should I be doing?

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587782/checking-on-some-convergent-series/587798#587798).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Can you elaborate on how the first derivative lets me know whether it is decreasing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a slightly alternative route: Using the fact that $(-1)^{n + 1} = - (-1)^n$, we can rewrite the series as

$$- \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac 2 3\right)^n$$

Let's erase the minus signs and consider the series

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac 23\right)^n$$

This is a geometric series; does it converge, or not?

Comment: Yes, it does converge because $\frac{2}{3}$ < 1. The sum would then be 3?

Comment: @ConfusingCalc Yes, it converges. Now we have an *absolutely* convergent series, and so the original series must be convergent as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I can assume the original series will be convergent as well based on the geometric series you outlined?

Comment: @ConfusingCalc Every absolutely convergent series is convergent as well. We've replaced all the terms with their absolute values here by erasing the minus signs - hence the original series converges absolutely.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you very much :) Am I correct about the sum though?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function

$$ f(x) = (2/3)^{x}=e^{x\ln(2/3)}$$

and note that $\ln(2/3) < 0$. Now, you need to check $f'(x) <0$