# $1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{4^3} + ..........$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{4^3} + ......$
Can anyone help me out how to solve this.

My try : I was thinking about the expansion of $tan^{-1}x$. But in that series  positive and negative will come alternatively.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580143/evaluate-1-frac13-frac14-frac15-frac142-frac17-frac – both found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%241%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%5E2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B7%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%5E3%7D%20%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(2r+1)}\left(\dfrac12\right)^{2r}=2\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2r+1}}{(2r+1)}$$ where $2x=1$

Now $-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}n$ for $-1\le x<1$

$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=?$

Alternatively, $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2r+1}}{(2r+1)}=\int\sum_{r=0}^\infty(x^2)^rdx$$

Comment: khubbbb bhalo @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: Which is more or less your answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/580148/42969 to an older question :)

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for searching out. I've voted for Duplicate

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to use binomial theorem . Consider the series expansion of $\ln (\frac {1}{1-x}),\ln (\frac {1}{1+x})$ using binomial expression for negative index we have $\ln (\frac {1}{1-x})-\ln (\frac {1}{1+x})=2 (x+\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^5}{5}+.. ) $ now pull out $x $ common from $RHS $ and put $x=\frac {1}{2} $ thus we have $\frac {1}{2x}\ln(\frac {1}{1-x})-\ln(\frac {1}{1+x})=S $ thus $S=\ln (3) $

Comment: did you mean "series expansion of $\ln (\frac{1}{1-x})$ and $\ln (\frac{1}{1+x})$", because the answer must be $\ln 3$?

Comment: Oh yes i made a mistake

Comment: It is ok. Two more points: 1) although it doesn't affect the final result, in the last part $1/2x$ is missing. 2) I am afraid your method repeats the previous method. Luck.