# Compute the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I was asked to sum up the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)3^n}$$

However, I tried to write it：
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)3^n}=\frac{1}{1*3} + \frac{1}{3*9} + \frac{1}{5*27}+...$$

I don't know what to do next.
Could you help me? Or give me some hints?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580143/42969

Answer (score 5):

[Hint:](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Real_Area_Hyperbolic_Tangent) $$\tanh^{-1}(x)=x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}+\dfrac{x^7}{7}+\cdots,\qquad  \vert x\vert<1. $$

Also, since $$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\dfrac12\ln\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right) ,\qquad  \vert x\vert<1$$ you should be able to use the Maclaurin series $$\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{0\le n}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1} ,\qquad  \vert x\vert<1$$ to evaluate the given series.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time to know the inverse tangent series!

Comment: @PandaChou: This is not the [Maclaurin series of inverse tangent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) It is that for the inverse hyperbolic tangent.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n-1)}$$
$$\frac { S(x)}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)}$$
$$\left(\frac { S(x)}x\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-2}=\frac 1 {1-x^2}$$ Integrate both sides
$$\frac { S(x)}x=\int \frac {dx}{1-x^2}=\int \frac {dx}{(1+x)(1-x)}=\frac 12 \int \left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\,dx$$  Now, it is simple.

Just replace $x$ by the appropriate value.

Comment: Thank you! This method is simpler. I like it!!